# SSRS default param expression today() vs now()

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a parameter of type date/time. I am creating a default value as expression. When I put

```
=IIF(Hour(TODAY()) < 1, 
    DateAdd("d", -1, FormatDateTime(Today(),DateFormat.ShortDate)),
    FormatDateTime(Today(),DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

it works well and return a value (although always the same, since the hour is always 0 (12AM))

But I want to base this default value on the CURRENT date time attime of report. So when I replace today() with NOW(), it errors out and says that it "doesn't have expected type".

```
=IIf(Hour(now())<1, 
    DateAdd("d",-1, FormatDateTime(Today(),DateFormat.ShortDate)),
    FormatDateTime(Today(),DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

Thanks

I tried multiple formulas to convert now() into something, but nothing worked.

Comment: `FormatDateTime` converts the date into a string, which is not a date-type. You can use CDATE to convert back into a date, but then why are you converting to a string in the first place when your parameter is a date?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the expression didn;t evaluate the second part of the IIF because the HOUR(Today) was always 0. The Format would convert the date into a string which would cause the error. Evidently, the DateAdd was converting the string back into a date in order to subtract the day.

I think you can do without all the converting.

```
=IIF(Hour(NOW()) < 1, 
    DateAdd("d", -1, Today()),
    Today())
```